# Angular2 Get Data but cant seem to get objects inside main holding object

Tags: angular

Fairly new to anuglar2,  I call a service to get some page content data but I cant seem to get the properties inside my main object. I can get the first layer of properties but when I want to go deep into the object I get this error message..

Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in [{{content.acf.title}} in HomeComponent@3:5]

This is my component below and the bindings i call

```
       import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
       import {ProductListComponent} from '../products/product- list.component.js';
       import {FeaturedProductsComponent} from './featured_products.component.js'
       import {VideoComponent} from './video.component.js';
       import {FooterComponent} from '../footer/footer.component.js';
       import {AppServices} from '../../app.services.js';

       @Component({
             templateUrl: "wp-content/themes/f2/app/views/pages/home-template.html",
             directives: [FeaturedProductsComponent, VideoComponent,FooterComponent],
             providers: [AppServices]
       })
       export class HomeComponent implements onInit {

            content:any = {};
            pageName: string = "home";
           errorMessage: string;

            constructor(
              private _AppServices: AppServices
             ) {}

            ngOnInit() {

             this._AppServices.getPageContent( this.pageName ).subscribe(
                data => this.content = data[0], 
               error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

           }

       }
```

In the template view I call this, the first binding works, but the second one doesn't

```
      <h1>{{content.slug}}</h1>
      <h1>{{content.acf.title}}</h1>
```

Here is the response I get
http://pastebin.com/JK8FtQUa

Comment: my main page object with data inside

Comment: I cant seem to go down the levers of the object, only the top layer binds

Comment: What do you see in your console when you replace `data => this.content = data[0],` with `data => this.content = data[0]; console.log(this.content),`

Answer (score 2):

Data from the server arrive with some delay and Angular runs into an error when it tries to resolve the binding before the data is available. You can easily fix this using the Elvis operator

```
 <h1>{{content?.slug}}</h1>
 <h1>{{content?.acf.hero_image.title}}</h1>
```

This way Angular doesn't try to evaluate the part after `?.` as long as `content` is `null`

Comment: I see. Didn't read the question properly. You can try adding `?` before `.title` as well but the problem is obviously with your data and we can't help debug without seeing it. Can you please add to you question what `console.log(data[0])` (instead of `this.content = data[0], `) prints to the console?

Comment: I get this when console log ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Comment: the expected object gets consoled logged

Comment: And what is this expected object? Can you share it with us please?

Comment: So it doesn't have an acf key?

Comment: What a mess. Can you please edit your question and add this in readable form there?

Comment: sorry will add the full object to the question now

Comment: No I didnt there is a title property in acf

Comment: "title": "BRAND AMBASSADOR",

Comment: I see. Then I have no idea. Is this pastebin from what you send from the server or what you receive on the client? Does it work if you assign this JSON statically in code instead of fetching it from the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111121/discussion-between-user3355603-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: I'm already in a chat and have too many windows open. I don't think I can provide much value. You just have to debug what's going on.